# java regex for multiline String

Tags: regex

```
begin
    dbms_utility.compile_schema(user, false);
end;
```

may i get regex for above string?
i am using below regex

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("begin*dbms_utility.compile_schema(user, false);*end;",Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(newtext);
        if (regexMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(regexMatcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("second regex : "+regexMatcher);
```

Comment: Is it a part of a longer string? At any rate, you may use `"begin\\s*dbms_utility\\.compile_schema\\(user,\\s*false\\);\\s*end;"`, either with `find()` or with `matches()` (if the entire string must match).

Comment: Could you explain what exactly do you need to match? I thought you need to match the *whole* string above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape some special chars (`(`, `)`, `.`) and use `\s` to match whitespace:

```
"begin\\s*dbms_utility\\.compile_schema\\(user,\\s*false\\);‌​\\s*end;"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L2Cw1q/1)

Note that using it with `find()` will find any substrings in longer strings, and using the expression with `Matcher#matches()` will only return true if the whole string matches the pattern.

To get the whole match, use `Matcher.group(0)`, to get the *capture group* values, use the index higher than `0`.

```
String regex = "begin\\s*(dbms_utility\\.compile_schema\\(user,\\s*false\\);)\\s*end;";
String string = "begin\n    dbms_utility.compile_schema(user, false);\nend;";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/y8f5IW).

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("DS \\#18 \\[([0-9\\.]*)\\\\([0-9\\.]*)\\] Pixel Spacing",
                            Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL); 
Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
while( m.find() ) {
    System.out.println("[ "+m.group( 1 )+", "+m.group( 2 )+" ]");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!